# Why a jsonp call using jquery behaving synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, jsonp

Iam trying to make a jsonp call using jquery ajax function using the below code. According to jquery documentation it should make a asynchronous call and not block other subsequent calls.

```
$.ajax({
         dataType: "jsonp",
         url: endpoint,
         data: params
});
```

But somehow the above call is blocking until the response has been received. Check the screenshot below which shows the timeline in chrome. You will see the call in red blocking the rest of execution until a response has been received.

[image]

Any clue what might be going wrong.?

Comment: Are you sure it is blocking *execution* and not the loading of other scripts?

Comment: Is the ajax request performed inside of a `$(document).ready(function() { [your code here] }` ? If it's not, the call might simply be preempting the load requests and the server is responding to the requests in order.

Comment: The simples answer is that your endpoint is incorrect, maybe the callback parameter is missing (url.of.my.server?callback=?), please provide more information